# Client Nodes are getting recreated, even after kill -k

Tags: ignite

Using apache ignite 1.7 
I Started ignite server node on system (collocated with spark) and from zeppelin created some client nodes (while execution pro), there were 5 client nodes created, Now I when I am trying to kill alnode and restart my server node, it agains shows 5 client nodes in topology , I want to completely discard those client node and want to start again as I have some changes in code and want that to be effective

Comment: Then just kill your client node, because ignite autodiscovers it and hence if it is present in the topology it will discover it

Answer (score 0):

I believe this are client nodes running embedded in Spark executors. Having them should not affect the ability to change the code.

Is there any specific issue associated with this behavior?

Comment: Yes , client node running embedded in spark executor, I am using distributed setup and on one of the services there were some server node running which were not killed, was facing problem because of those, after kill (linux kill) and deleting work folder started again an it worked. however facing other issue, I will ask that as separate question